# How to fetch JSON data from Flutter

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

Ive been trying to fetch json data from my flutter app. I managed to print the whole json on my console. I want to get only the "score" value from this json. How should I do it?

```
  final String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5aa3f9ee310000c21926e2f8";

  Future<String> getJsonData() async{
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept" : "application/json"}
    );
     print(response.body);

    List data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data[0]["score"]);

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your last two lines as

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
 print(data["score"]);
```

**Explanation**:
Data you receive from API is not JSON Array its JSON object so you should decode response to Map, & get score field from that map.